# How can I make an interactive graph of chartSeries (quantmod) in R?

Tags: r, plotly, quantmod

I have the graph from the quantmod package in which I get data from SPY, I want to make an interactive graph, similar to how we would do it with `ggploty` from the `plotly` package. This is the basic form of my code.

```
library(quantmod)
library(plotly)
getSymbols("SPY", from="2016-01-01", to="2020-01-01")
chartSeries(SPY, subset = "2017-11-18::2017-12-16")
addSMA(n=50, on=1, col = "blue")
```

This is what I tried to do

```
p <- chartSeries(SPY, subset = "2017-11-18::2017-12-16")
ggplotly(p)
```

This code doesn't work, I think it has a different class object. Is there a way to make the graph from `chartSeries` an interactive graph so I can select a specific range of data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the dygraphs package to create an interactive chart with an object of xts class

try the code below,
it will create an interactive chart with candlestick of of the prices

```
library(quantmod)
library(dygraphs)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(htmlwidgets)
getSymbols("SPY", from="2016-01-01", to="2020-01-01")


SPY <- SPY[,c(1:4)] ## remove the volume and adjusted columns
SPY$SMA50 <- SMA(Cl(SPY), n = 50) #create SMA50 line
p <- dygraph(SPY, xlab = "Date", ylab = "Price", main = "SPY Price") %>%
  dySeries("SPY.Open", label = "Open", color = "black") %>%
  dySeries("SPY.Low", label = "Low", color = "red") %>%
  dySeries("SPY.High", label = "High", color = "green") %>%
  dySeries("SPY.Close", label = "Close", color = "orange") %>%
  dySeries("SMA50", label = "SMA50", color = "blue") %>%
  dyRangeSelector() %>%
  dyCandlestick()%>%
  dyCrosshair(direction = "vertical") %>%
  dyHighlight(highlightCircleSize = 3, highlightSeriesBackgroundAlpha = 0.2, hideOnMouseOut = T)  %>%
  dyRoller(rollPeriod = 1)
p
```